# iOS: Notifications and iBeacon

Tags: ios, notifications, core-location, ibeacon

I have an app that needs to send notifications when user is out of range of iBeacon. The problem is that user becomes notifications randomly: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work. 
My code:

```
// this function I call in viewDidLoad for my UIViewController

func startMonitorig() {
    let beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = {
        let r = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")!, major: 1, minor: 6, identifier: "com.myapp.identifier")
        return r
    }()
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     locationManager.delegate = self
     locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
     startMonitorig()

}
```

AppDelegate:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Request permission to send notifications
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in }
    locationManager.delegate = self

    return true
}   

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    guard region is CLBeaconRegion else { return }

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Forget Me Not"
    content.body = "Are you forgetting something?"
    content.sound = .default()

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "ForgetMeNot", content: content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

}

I'm curious why it's like that and what I'm doing wrong? What can be the reason?

Comment: Region exits fire only when (1) a matching beacon has been detected (2) 30 seconds to 15 minutes pass with no subsequent detections. Are you sure you are satisfying these conditions? How do you know?  How long do you wait?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes, (1) yes (I have output. it shows me info about connected iBeacon.). (2) maybe I'm waiting not enough... I'm not so experienced with local notifications. thank you for your response